# Sculpt mode destroying back of model

Tags: vertices, sculpting, dynamic-topology

[image: visible extra unwanted vertices]
Hi everyone,

Was feeling really pleased with the progress of these tiles, until I rotated the model and saw that everything I have been doing has not just been sculpting the top surface? Inside the model there is alot of added vertices, some of which spill out of the edges.

My workflow is as follows: Imported Illustrator rectangle, -> convert to mesh -> add modifier (solidify) -> subdivide to 10. Then enter sculpting mode making sure Dynotopo is clicked on. I also have ticked in brush settings > advanced check if "front faces only". Then using sculpting tools to create the drawings I want for an embossed tile look .

I have tried to flatten away the excess parts but that ends up destroying the design on the top.

often these vertices are not visible whilst sculpting but become visible when i click back to layout mode.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solidify modifier not being applied is your problem. Because the original mesh surface was still just a flat plane set, you are equivalently sculpting the flat surface, then solidifying it. Delete the solidify modifier, go to edit mode, select all, select boundary loop (the border of the rectangle), extrude it, and then create a face.

Comment: thanks! i will try this !

Comment: @SORRELMADLEY I hope it helps .